# Swing. Fill JScrollPane with JList

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, jlist

I'm doing a window aplication. I need to create a JScrollPane and then fill it with a String[]. The problem is that I need to refresh it.

I want an empty JScrollPane when I start the aplication and when I press any button, the button will refresh the JScrollPane.

I have all the code, I only need refresh the content:

```
    // Empty JScrollPane
    scrollPaneDic = new JScrollPane(new JList());
    scrollPaneDic.setBounds(225, 75, 200, 170);

    // Layout
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblPalabrasDiccionario);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPaneDic);
```

And in the button actionListener is where I have to refresh the content:

```
    String[] newContent = (method generate and return the new array);
    listDic = new JList(newContent);
    scrollPaneDic = new JScrollPane(listDic);
```

**Important**: scrollPaneDic and listDic are global

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262669/refresh-jlist-in-a-jframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing a variable's value does not affect a component's state in any way;  you must call a component method.  Until you do that, your frame has no way of knowing that you created a new JScrollPane.

Actually, you should not create a new JScrollPane or a new JList.  Instead, you should update the existing JList:

```
JList listDic = (JList) scrollPaneDic.getViewport().getView();
listDic.setListData(newContent);
```

Also, using a null layout is strongly discouraged, especially for a JScrollPane.  Try resizing your window, or try changing the size of your system fonts before you run the application, and you will see why.  Not every user's system is like yours.